# Чому "поліпшення" витіснило "покращення"?

Tags: вживання-слів

У [СловОписі](http://slovopys.kubg.edu.ua/pokrashchennia-chy-polipshennia-sprav/) знайшла цікаву інформацію:

> Пам’ятаєте, як ще зовсім недавно нам обіцяли “покращення”? А далі не обіцяли, але ж знову воно з’явилось, це “покращення”. Тепер ми точно знаємо, що ми його не хочемо. А хочемо поліпшення. І хочемо так, що якщо й будуть нам знову його обіцяти, то ми не повіримо, поки не побачимо!  Ось така непроста ця словесна конструкція, за якою – пласт і політики, й економіки, й людських сподівань, й обдурювання, й наївності, й надії, і чого завгодно…

Це твердження є нормативним? Адже, у [Академічному тлумачному словнику (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokrashhennja) знайшла 2 слова:

> ПОКРА́ЩЕННЯ, я, сер., рідко. Дія за значенням покращити.
>
> ПОЛІ́ПШЕННЯ, я, сер. Дія і стан за знач. поліпшити і поліпшитися.

[Академічний тлумачний словник (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/polipshennja).

Але слово **"ліпше"** знаходжу в [Лексиконі львівському](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53403/1064177.html):

> **лі́пше** - краще (м, ср, ст)♦ лі́пше раз, як ніра́зу (Франко),

отже це діалектизм і його не нормативно вживати ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обидва слова є синонімами, а також і нормативними, проте вживаються у різних значеннях. На сайті [UA INFO](http://uainfo.org/blognews/1487343848-chomu-zamist-pokrashchennya-mae-buti-polipshennya.html) пишуть:

> Борис Антоненко-Давидович має цілковиту рацію. Прикметник **ліпший** *та похідні від нього поліпшити, **поліпшення*** варто вживати частіше, особливо коли йдеться **не** про зовнішню вроду чи красу.

Так вважає і доцент кафедри української мови УжНУ *Вероніка Баньої* у [рубриці «Як правильно?» від «Ранку на Тисі»](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AYck2uC4VE):

> **покращити** утворене від слова кращий, а кращий — це вищий ступінь порівняння прикметників (від красивий, **пов’язаний з красою**).
>
> **поліпшення** вживається у значенні **“потреба щось змінити”**.

Щодо того, чи слово “поліпшення” є діалектизмом, то відповідь: ні. Оскільки позначки “діал.” нема ні в наведеному Вами СУМі, ні на Офіційному сайті Української мови ([тут](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/v/vdoskonalennja/24-1-0-2043) подають, що це синоніми), на сайті [ACADEMIC.COM](http://www.enacademic.com/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BF%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&from=xx&to=en&did=&stype=0) теж позначки такої нема.